# How to perform same resource filtering for both gretty and war?

Tags: gradle, war, gretty

Here's a snippet of a Gradle build script that filters web.xml both when building a WAR and when running the webapp with gretty's appRun task. Is there a way to share a single 'filesMatching' definition instead of repeating it?

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

def tokens = [
        "foo": "bar",
]

war {
    filesMatching("WEB-INF/web.xml") {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: tokens)
    }
}

gretty {
    webappCopy {
        filesMatching 'WEB-INF/web.xml', {
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: tokens)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [gretty documentation](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Web-app-filtering.html#_effects), any configuration added to `webappCopy` will be automatically added to `war` by the plugin.